# How to Change Spring Cloud Eureka Server Logo and CSS

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Is there a way to change Spring Cloud Eureka Server

1. Logo
2. CSS

Without changing source code of the Eureka Server. (i.e. By setting a property in application.yml, and/or placing an image/css file in a resource directory)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your logo and put into resources folder

[image: src/main/resources]

then override configuration for the logo resource of eureka

[image: resource configuration]

new logo:

[image: new logo]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.